# Modify scheduled query credentials

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to update the credentials of some scheduled queries to a service account. I read that I can't make the change from the Google console UI.

I tried to update the credentials using Python and `bq` CLI like so:

```py
import subprocess
import json

service_account_email = "scheduled-query-sa@economedia-analytics-prod-f90p.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

query_list_command = "bq ls -j --format=json"
query_list_output = subprocess.check_output(query_list_command, shell=True)
query_list = json.loads(query_list_output)

for query in query_list:
    query_id = query["config"]["transferConfig"]["name"]
    display_name = query["config"]["transferConfig"]["displayName"]

    update_command = f"bq update --transfer_config --update {query_id} --service_account_email {service_account_email}"
    
    subprocess.call(update_command, shell=True)

    print(f"Updated credentials for scheduled query '{display_name}' (ID: {query_id}) to use the service account.")

print("All scheduled queries updated.")
```

and

```bash
bq update --transfer_config --update test \
--service_account_email 'test-sa@your-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
```

I'm not sure what this transfer_config is and how to get it in the Python code.

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer

transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()

project_id = "my-project"
parent = transfer_client.common_project_path(project_id)

configs = transfer_client.list_transfer_configs(parent=parent)
print("Got the following configs:")
for config in configs:
    print(f"\tID: {config.name}, Schedule: {config.schedule}")
```

The above code returned this error:

> PermissionDenied: 403 BigQuery Data Transfer service has not been used
> in project 1043443670838 before or it is disabled.

Is this transfer configuration necessary for updating to service account credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this example(as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#update_scheduled_query_credentials)):

```
bq update \
--update_credentials \
--service_account_name=abcdef-test-sa@abcdef-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com projects/862514376110/locations/us/transferConfigs/5dd12f26-0000-262f-bc38-089e0820fe38
--transfer_config \
projects/myproject/locations/us/transferConfigs/1234a123-1234-1a23-1be9-12ab3c456de7
```

or

```
bq update \
--transfer_config \
--update_credentials \
--service_account_name=abcdef-test-sa@abcdef-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com projects/862514376110/locations/us/transferConfigs/5dd12f26-0000-262f-bc38-089e0820fe38 \
```

Additionally you can list scheduled queries by:

`bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=LOCATION --filter='dataSourceIds:scheduled_query'`

Also it appears that update flag is not available within the bq update command.The transfer config flag is whether to update the transfer configuration or not.

Another option (for non service account ) is to update through console:
[image]

Reference for bq command tool and it flags here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#synopsis_21